# How to show only the proper lead source based on product category chosen

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-marketing-cloud, salesforce-development

We have 3 product categories in Salesforce and we are generating leads and the lead sources may differ based on the product category.

The use-case is that only the proper lead sources should be displayed based on the product category chosen.

Since lead source is a standard field, it can not be used as a dependent field. So we are looking for one of this 3 approaches:

1. New page layouts for each product category and filter the Lead Source field based on product category
2. A new business process and 3 record types for each product category
3. 3 business processes and 3 record types for each product category

As far as we analyzed this scenario, solution number 2 may be the most effective and easier to implement. Do you guys have any other suggestions? - Thanks!